# How can be extract the data through RPA on a Date field

Tags: automation, rpa, automationanywhere

I want to extract the data through Robotic Automation Process on a date field (To and from) .How can i select this field without using capture function as the selection position of the data(To & from) will change for each months.How to deal with this issue in Automation Anywhere tool

I want to automate the sales order report through automation anywhere toll but could not able to do so as date field is mandatory to select and showing calender in which position of the date will change foe each months

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.